# how to find the difference of dataframe which is given on start date and end date

Tags: python, pandas

I have to find the difference in data provided at 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 per day for seven days.
How to find the difference in the data frame, which is given on the start date and end date?

Sample Data

```
Date                         Data
2018-12-01 00:00:00          2
2018-12-01 12:00:00          5
2018-12-01 23:59:59          10
2018-12-02 00:00:00          12
2018-12-02 12:00:00          15
2018-12-02 23:59:59          22
```

Expected Output

```
Date                        Data
2018-12-01                   8
2018-12-02                   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {
    'Date': ['2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 12:00:00', '2018-12-01 23:59:59',
             '2018-12-02 00:00:00', '2018-12-02 12:00:00', '2018-12-02 23:59:59'],
    'Data': [2, 5, 10, 12, 15, 22]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

**Code**

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
out = (df.resample('D', on='Date')['Data']
       .agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).reset_index())
```

`out`

```
    Date        Data
0   2018-12-01  8
1   2018-12-02  10
```

---

**Update**

more efficient way

you can get same result following code:

```
g = df.resample('D', on='Date')['Data']
out = g.last().sub(g.first()).reset_index()
```

Comment: Why not use first and last, or `nth(-1) - nth(0)` should be faster and you can reuse on the groupby object or use `pipe`

Comment: @sammywemmy I've written code that I think is the easiest to understand. Your request has been updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby and iterate over with min-max range.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 12:00:00', '2018-12-01 23:59:59', 
             '2018-12-02 00:00:00', '2018-12-02 12:00:00', '2018-12-02 23:59:59'],
    'Data': [2, 5, 10, 12, 15, 22]
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Date_Only'] = df['Date'].dt.date
result = df.groupby('Date_Only').apply(lambda x: x['Data'].max() - x['Data'].min())

print(result)
```